# Não estou conseguindo finalizar as Activitys

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin, android-intent

O meu problema é o seguinte... Eu tenho 3 Activitys:

(ActivityA), (ActivityB) e (ActivityC)

Da ActivityA apara a ActivityB eu faço o seguinte:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
```

da ActivityB para a ActivityC Eu também faço a mesma coisa:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
```

Acontece que se eu der onBackPressed ou ir para qualquer outro App e retornar para o meu App em vez de voltar para a ActivityC como era o esperado eu sempre retorno para a ActivityA!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

O flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` faz com que a activity não entre para pilha do histórico. Por isso ao alterar entre apps e voltar o Android não tem o histórico de qual a activity estava aberta no app e reinicia o app, chamando a activity launcher novamente que no seu caso deve ser a ActivityA.

E os flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` e `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` vão limpar da pilha do histórico todas as activity aberta anteriormente. Por isso ao pressionar o onBackPressed em vez de voltar para ultima activity aberta, vai fechar por completo o app, e ao voltar o Android abrirá da activity launcher.

Caso queira que mesmo fechando o app ele volte para a activity que estava anteriormente, você precisa criar um controle, por exemplo, salvar no SharedPreferencs onde o usuario estava, e na activity launcher redirecionar.